# dumping/restoring single schema from the main big database

Tags: mysql, database

I know we can dump and restore the complete database. But, I want to know if I have multiple database or schema in one main database then what will be the syntax for that?

My database name is TEST and I tried following syntax:

```
### Start MySQL Backup ###
#$MYSQLDUMP -Q -u root -p "database TEST" >/usr/db/backup/"database TEST".sql;
$MYSQLDUMP -uroot "database TEST" >/backup/"database TEST"-$NOW-$(date +"%T").sql;
```

But, it failed with following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$MYSQLDUMP -uroot "database omertest" >/backup/"database omertest"-$NOW-$(date +' at line 1

Comment: Why you use $MYSQLDUMP ?  I mean $ symbol

Answer (score 0):

If you want only schema then use this command to dump:

```
MYSQLDUMP  -u root -p --no-data TEST >/usr/db/backup/db_backup.sql;
```

Comment: the one u mention syntax is still not right. may be a little small error. Can you paste exactly one more time

Comment: you can use even more modified :

MYSQLDUMP  -u root -p --no-data --database TEST >/usr/db/backup/db_backup.sql;

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: my Server version: 5.1.67 Source distribution

Comment: how ever my server team once told me that the script should be the following: ### Start MySQL Backup ###
#$MYSQLDUMP -Q -u root -p "database name" >/usr/db/backup/"database name".sql;
$MYSQLDUMP -uroot "database name" >/backup/"database name"-$NOW-$(date +"%T").sql;